# How and When LINQ Queries are Translated and Evaluated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, lambda

I have a LINQ to SQL Query as below:

```
var carIds = from car in _db.Cars
           where car.Color == 'Blue'
           select car.Id;
```

The above will be translated into the below sql finally:

```
select Id from Cars 
where Color = 'Blue'
```

I've read that the phases are:

1. LINQ to Lambda Expression
2. Lambda Expression to Expression Trees
3. Expression Trees to SQL Statements
4. SQL Statements gets executed

So, my questions are when and how does this get translated and executed?

I know that phase 4 happens at runtime when my "carIds" variable get accessed within a foreach loop.

```
foreach(var carId in carIds) // here?
{
  Console.Writeline(carId) // or here?
}
```

What about the other phases? when do they occur? at compile time or runtime? at which line (on the definition or after the definition, when accessed or before it gets accessed)?

Comment: I think this depends on the orm-mapper you are using.

Comment: @Grumbler85 it's LINQ to SQL, as OP mentioned in the very first line.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is ***deferred execution*** - essentially, the linq to SQL query will be executed at the time you attempt to enumerate the results (e.g. iterate round it, .ToArray() it etc).

In your example, the statement is executed on the following line:

```
foreach(var carId in carIds)
```

See this MSDN article on [LINQ and Deferred Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it's executed when enumerated at runtime. What about the translation? how/when the translation happens?

Comment: @TheLight OBVIOUSLY the translation happens then also. Because if you write that stuff in LAMBDA expressions, you can actually dynamically extend the query tree. Phase 1 is compiler, all Phase 2 does not exist (the lampda IS the expression tree), the other phases only happen "when needed".

Comment: @TomTom I disagree: step 2 most definitely exists, and is done by the compiler. Going from `x => x.Foo == 2` to `ParameterExpression p0; var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeType, bool>>(Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField((p0 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeType), "x")), "Foo"), Expression.Constant(2, typeof(int))), p0);` (plus the static-cache that it does for re-usable expressions) doesn't just happen out of nowhere. That is a real, genuine step - and is done by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

1. is done by either you, the dev, or the C# compiler; you can write lambda expression manually, or with LINQ syntax they can be implied from LINQ (i.e. `where x.Foo == 12` is treated as though it were `.Where(x => x.Foo == 12)`, and then the compiler processes step 2 based on that)
2. is done by the C# compiler; it translates the "lambda expression" into IL that constructs (or re-uses, where possible) an expression tree. You could also argue that the runtime is what *processes* this step
3. and
4. are typically done when the query is **enumerated**, specifically when `foreach` calls `GetEnumerator()` (and possibly even deferred to the first `.MoveNext`)

the deferred execution allows queries to be *composed*; for example:

```
var query = ...something complex...
var items = query.Take(20).ToList();
```

here the `Take(20)` is performed *as part of* the overall query, so you don't bring back everything from the server and *then* (at the caller) filter it to the first 20; only 20 rows are ever retrieved from the server.

You can also use compiled queries to restrict the query to just step 4 (or steps 3 and 4 in some cases where the query needs different TSQL depending on parameters). Or you can skip everything except 4 if you write just TSQL to start with.

You should also add a step "5": materialization; this is quite a complex and important step. In my experience, the materialization step can actually be the ***most significant*** in terms of overall performance (hence why we wrote "dapper").

Comment: 3) will be cached if it's used with EF5, won't it?

Comment: @Grumbler85 that is an implementation detail, but the "check the cache" stage would still happen at the point indicated (i.e. when the query is enumerated)

Comment: Are you sure that 3 does not happen until you enumerate? I thought that most of the translation would be done by then, because I'd get an exception if my query cannot be translated even if I do not attempt enumerating it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight very sure. Because right up until you enumerate, you have the option to compose the query more. As per the example (in my answer) of adding a `.Take(20)`. You **cannot** generate TSQL until you know what the complete query is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight re your exception, that would genuinely surprise me - but yes, it would be possible to spot things that **cannot be handled** earlier in the pipe. That sanity checking has nothing to do with TSQL generation, though.